# Quisiera saber como llenar una matriz bidimensional a partir de una unidimensional

Tags: java, matriz

Tengo que realizar un trabajo que consiste en que tengo una matriz bidimensional con ciertas posiciones ya llenas, pasarla a una matriz unidimensinal que ya logré) pero como último paso debo visualizar los datos de la matriz unidimensional como una bidimensional. Entonces en el método visualizar paso como datos la posicion de la fila y columna para poder almacenarlos y utilizo v como índice para poder utilizar los valores de la matriz MU que estan en orden por fila,columna,valor,fila,columna,valor... por lo que solo debo tomar posiciones de 3 en 3. El problema es que cuando lleno la matriz bi solo me guarda los segundos valores de cada fila y me ignora los demás. Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano!!!

public class Test6 {

```
static  int po =0, po2=1;
static int datos[] = new int[16];
static int [] MU = new int [24];
static int[][] bi = new int[4][4];

public static void CrearMatriz(int []m, int f, int c, int v){
   
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (m[i]>0 && m[i]<10) {
            if ((v%2)==0){
                datos[po] = m[i];
                po = po+2;
            }else if((v%2)==1){
                datos[po2] = m[i];
                po2 = po2 +2;
            }
        }
    }

       int r= 15;
       for (int i = 23; i > 0; i-=3) {
           MU[i] = datos[r];
           r= r-2;
        }
       
    for (int i = v; i < MU.length; i+=3) {
        MU[i] = f;
        
    }
   for (int j = v+1; j < MU.length; j+=3) {
            MU[j] = c;
        }

  Visualizar(f,c,v );
}//fin del método

 public static void Visualizar(int fi, int co, int v){
      
     bi[fi][co] = MU[v+2];
      
 }//fin del método
```

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
   int[][] b = new int[4][4];
    b[0][1] = 2;    b[0][3] = 6;
    b[1][3] = 8;    b[1][0] = 1;
    b[2][2] = 9;    b[2][3] = 4;
    b[3][0] = 7;    b[3][1] = 5;

   int val=0;
   for (int f = 0; f <b.length; f++) {
   for (int c = 0; c < b.length; c++){ 
   if((b[f][c]) >0 && (b[f][c] <10)){
   CrearMatriz(b[f], f, c, val*3);
   val++;
       }
             }
    }

    System.out.println("Matriz unidimensional");
 for (int i = 0; i < MU.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(MU[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Matriz bidimensional");
    for (int i = 0; i < bi.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bi[i]));
    }
```

}}

Comment: Hola Victor, sinceramente no logro entender, se supone que recibes un array "uni" y debes visualizarlo como "bi", ahora bien, si es así, debes recibir un dato (otro array?) que nos indique como transformar el "uni" en "bi", podrías agregar a tu pregunta esos datos y la salida esperada?.

Comment: Es que el ejercicio consta de pasar una matriz bidimensional a una unidimensional pasando la posición de la fila y columna, posteriormente con la matriz unidimensional volver a pasarla a bidimensional

Comment: Osea, la matriz inicial es "b", hay que pasarla a uni y después pasar esa uni a bi, estoy en lo cierto?

Comment: Exactamente, aún trabajo en ello

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí,  espero pueda ayudarte: para pasar de bidimensional a unidimensional simplemente recorres la matriz por fila y columna. La matriz unidimensional debe tener tantos elementos como tiene la matriz bidimensional:

```
static int filas=4;
static int columnas=4;

static int[][] bi = new int[filas][columnas];
static int [] MU = new int [filas*columnas];


// pasando a unidireccional

for(int=0;i<filas;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<columnas; j++){
        MU[(i*filas)+j]=bi[i][j]
    }

}


// Visualizar arreglo uni como bi

for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
    
    for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
// si quieres visualizar los que tienen solo valor aquí tendrías que poner el filtro if
System.out.print(MU[(i*filas)+j]+ " ");
     }
     System.out.println(); // nueva línea por cada fila

    
    

}
```

El algoritmo es calcular la posición que le corresponde un elemento unidimensional en el arreglo bidimensional:

```
    bi[i][j]=mu[(i*NUMERO_FILAS)+j]

// siendo 0 <= i < FILAS
```

Por ejemplo, el elemento bi[2][2] estará en la posición  (2×4)+2=10, es decir en la posición. 10 del arreglo unidimensional. Las posiciones son en base a 0.

Por otro lado, la posición en el arreglo unidimensional le corresponde al elemento:

```
// Calcular la fila y columna de un elemento
   Mu[possicion]= bi[(int(posicion/filas)][residuo posicion/filas)
```

Por ejemplo, el elemento 10 de la matriz unidimensional está en: (10/4)=2 (10%4)=2, es decir wn bi[2][2].

NOTA; Estoy en duda si quieres llenar una matriz bidimensional o crear un unidimensional en base a la bidimensional. Esta respuesta es sobre este último.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] crearMatrizUnidimensional( int[][] matOriginal ) {
   int salida[] = new int[ matOriginal.length * matOriginal[ 0 ].length * 3];      
   int auxiliar = 0;
   for( int i = 0; i < matOriginal.length; i++ ) {
      for( int h = 0; h < matOriginal[ 0 ].length; h++ ) {
         salida[ auxiliar ] = matOriginal[ i ][ h ];
         salida[ auxiliar +1 ] = i;
         salida[ auxiliar +2 ] = h;
         auxiliar += 3;
      }
   }
   return salida;
}

public static int[][] crearMatrizBidimensional( int datos[] ) {
   int a = datos.length; 
   int salida[][] = new int[ datos[ a -2 ] +1 ][ datos[ a -1 ] +1 ]; 
   int salto = 0;
   for( int i = 0; i < datos.length / 3; i ++ ) {
      salida[ datos[ salto +1 ] ][ datos[ salto + 2 ] ] = datos[ salto ];
      salto +=3;
   }
   return salida ;
}

public static void Visualizar( int data[][] ) {      
  for( int i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
     for( int h = 0; h < data[ 0 ].length; h ++ ) {
        System.out.print( data[ i ][ h ] );
     }
     System.out.println("");
  }
}

public static void Visualizar( int fi[] ) {      
   for( int i = 0; i < fi.length; i += 3 ) {    
      System.out.print( fi[ i ] );     
   }   
}


public static void main( String[] args ) {
   int[][] b = new int[ 4 ][ 4 ];
   b[ 0 ][ 1 ] = 2;
   b[ 0 ][ 3 ] = 6;
   b[ 1 ][ 3 ] = 8;
   b[ 1 ][ 0 ] = 1;      
   b[ 2 ][ 2 ] = 9;
   b[ 2 ][ 3 ] = 4;
   b[ 3 ][ 0 ] = 7;
   b[ 3 ][ 1 ] = 5;

   int unidimensional[] = crearMatrizUnidimensional( b );
   int bidimensional[][] = crearMatrizBidimensional( unidimensional );
   visualizar( unidimensional );
   visualizar( bidimensional );
}
```

Bueno, costo, creamos un método **crearMatrizUnidimensional** que recibe como parámetro el array bidimensional que hay que "unidimensionalizar".
Primero instanciamos el array de salida, con el valor que sale de multiplicar las dos dimeniones de array de entrada entre si (nos da la cantidad de datos) y por tres, este "tres", se debe a que debemos guardar en el array no solo el dato, sino su posición dentro del array bidimensional (fila y columna), para después poder reconstruirlo.

Luego dentro con dos for, recorremos el array recibido, y por cada valor, asignamos en la salida tres valores, el dato, la columna y la fila, eso lo logramos con "auxiliar", que va incrementando su valor en 3.

El método **crearMatrizBidimensional**, recibe un array, de los ultimos dos valores del mismo, toma la cantidad de columnas y filas del array a construir, e inicializa el array de salida.

Dentro del for, recorremos el array creado, y le asignamos los valores correspondientes, sabemos que el array recibido contiene el dato, la columna y la fila, estructura que se repite, solo tomamos esos valores para saber que   columna y fila tenemos que instanciar y con que valor.

Espero haber sido claro, es bastante difícil de explicar.

Comment: Correcto, solo mi duda es que intente correr el programa pero me mandar un error al llamar a los métodos Visualizar y no entiendo el porqué

Comment: A mi me funcionan, los has modificado?

Comment: Puede ser que el "cortito", está hecho para imprimir solamente los datos y no las posiciones, por eso "salta" de 3 en 3, solo sirve para imprimir el array creado con **crearMatrizUnidimensional**. Si necesitas imprimir otro array, deberás renombrar este y crear otro método.

Comment: Ya me funcionó, era que el visualizar venía en minúscula pero me decía otro error, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Un placer poder ayudarte!!